# Debian with Wacom Intuos S, BT tablet

Tags: debian, wacom

I have Wacom Intuos S, BT CTL-4100WL tablet and debian Stretch can't see it (both usb and bluetooth).On Windows 10 works fine.

```
lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:0376 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

Comment: What Debian version are you running?

Comment: what does "lsusb" report when the tablet is connected?

Comment: Debian version: Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: lsusb: Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:0376 Wacom Co., Ltd

Comment: i did it and i didn't get any error but still doesn't work

Comment: Do you have the Wacom drivers installed? run `which xsetwacom` to check

Comment: i go this "/usr/bin/xsetwacom"

Comment: try `aptitude versions xserver-xorg-input-wacom` and see if you are up to date with 0.34.0-1

Comment: i   0.34.0-1                                      stable                    500

Comment: I'm guessing `xsetwacom --list dev` comes back blank?

Comment: yes i didn't get something back

Comment: Can't figure out why the tablet isn't working for you, should be supported. My last guess would be trying this - https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source